# Sprites not being destroyed when interacted with

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am creating a simple platformer where the enemies die when jumped on; I am calling a method from my enemyController

```
public void Hurt()
{
    Destroy(this.gameObject);

}
```

The console says this when I jump on them:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Enemy' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
> Enemy.Hurt () (at Assets/Scripts/Enemy.cs:48)
> CharacterController2D.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D collision) (at Assets/Scripts/CharacterController2D.cs:188)

The script that references the method is in my characterController

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        foreach(ContactPoint2D point in collision.contacts)
        {
            Debug.Log(point.normal);
            Debug.DrawLine(point.point,point.point+point.normal, Color.yellow, 10);
            if(point.normal.y >= 0.6f)
            {
                Vector2 velocity = rb2d.velocity;
                velocity.y = jumpForce;
                rb2d.velocity = velocity;
                enemy.Hurt();
            }
            else
            {
                rb2d.AddForce(new Vector3(-transform.position.x,jumpForce, transform.position.z));
                Hurt();
                animator.SetBool("isHit", true);
            }
        }
```

It checks whether the player is above the enemies and if so it destroys them; if not the player takes damage and is knocked back(The knockback is not yet implemented). Why do my enemies not get destroyed. They are not spawned in via script

Comment: They are destroyed via script. You are cutting off the branch over which you are standing, i.e. you destroy the enemy then try to use it again. Either have the player destroy the enemy, or have another manager that checks all the enemies and destroys those that have no more life. Having an object destroy itself is a risky architecture and should be handled with great care.

Comment: Where do you assign your `enemy` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OnCollisionEnter2D()` function, you have this line of code:

```
enemy.Hurt();
```

You don't set the value of `enemy` anywhere in that function. It's likely that `enemy` is always pointed at the same enemy, so each time you call `Hurt()` it's actually on the same enemy (not necessarily the one you collided with) and thus `Hurt()` is getting called on the same enemy more than once.

It should probably look like this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        var enemy = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>() //You need this line!
        foreach(ContactPoint2D point in collision.contacts) {
            if(point.normal.y >= 0.6f)
            {
                Vector2 velocity = rb2d.velocity;
                velocity.y = jumpForce;
                rb2d.velocity = velocity;
                enemy.Hurt();
            }
        //etc etc
```